# Line break and vertical alignment of other cells in NiceMatrix

Tags: vertical-alignment, nicematrix

I want to have both rows bottom aligned, using `NiceMatrix` package, specifying linebreak in one of the cells.

If I only have a long text in the first column, without further specification, then by defining bottom alignment of the second column in the declaration of the `NiceMatrix` environment, there is no problem, the content of the second column remains bottom aligned (both columns are):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{8cm}{X[2,l,b]X[2,r,b]}[hvlines]
    I write a rather long text that will be spread over more than one lines & Bottom-aligned text \\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, I still want to have both columns bottom-aligned, but I want to specify where I want to have the linebreak in the first column. If I simply add a rowbreak, `NiceMatrix` considers that I want to create a new row, and not to specify a linebreak in a cell (which is perfectly fine):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{8cm}{X[2,l,b]X[2,r,b]}[hvlines]
    I write another rather long text \\ that will be spread over more than one lines & Other bottom-aligned text \\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So far, when I wanted to add a linebreak in a cell, I would create a 1-1 block. But, in that case, it results in the right column being strangely (and, in any case, not bottom-)aligned.\par

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{8cm}{X[2,l,b]X[2,r,b]}[hvlines]
    \Block{1-1}{I write another rather long text \\ that will be spread over more than one lines} & Other bottom-aligned text \\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you have any idea on how I could get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `\newline` where you want to break a line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabularX}{8cm}{X[2,l,b]X[2,r,b]}[hvlines]
    I write another rather long text \newline that will be spread over more than one lines & Other bottom-aligned text \\
\end{NiceTabularX}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]